# exporting to powerpoint using a function to create graphs

Tags: r, ggplot2, powerpoint

I’m currently trying to export multiple graphs into the same Powerpoint presentation in R. The multiple graphs are created using a function.
However, when I run the code below it produces a separate Powerpoint for each of the variables (I want them in the same one for each of Calc_Commissiona and CalcCommission_Perc), Age_Banded, InstalmentsRequestedInd and NetPrem_Banded. This is because the ggsave just looks at the last plot I’m assuming.
Any ideas?
Also, the CreateGraph function is just producing the graph for CalcCommission Perc. Both CalcCommission and CalcCommission_Perc work independently when the other is removed…

```
require(ggplot2)

require(RDCOMClient)

require(R2PPT)

date <- "20160401"


CalcCommission  <- function(Variable,FName,AxisAngle){

    Actual_Commission <- tapply(Converted_A$Commission,Converted_A[Variable],mean)
  Predicted_Commission <- tapply(Final_cut$Commission_Response*Final_cut$Origination.Demand,Final_cut[Variable],sum)/tapply(Final_cut$Origination.Demand,Final_cut[Variable],sum)/100

Data <- data.frame(x=names(Actual_Commission),Actual_Commission,Predicted_Commission)
   Commission_Plot <- ggplot(Data,aes(x=seq(length(unique(x))))) +
    geom_line(aes(y=Actual_Commission, colour = "Actual Commission")) + 
    geom_line(aes(y=Predicted_Commission, colour = "Predicted Commission")) +
    scale_x_continuous(name = FName, 
                       breaks = seq(length(unique(Data$x))), 
                       labels = unique(Data$x))   +
    scale_y_continuous(name = "Commission £") +
    ggtitle("Commission £") +
    theme(legend.title=element_blank(),axis.text.x = element_text(angle = AxisAngle, hjust = 1))

  mypres <- PPT.Init(method="RDCOMClient")
  mypres<-PPT.AddTitleSlide(mypres,title="Commission £",subtitle=date)

  ggsave(my_temp_file<-paste(tempfile(),".wmf",sep=""), plot=Commission_Plot)
  mypres <- PPT.AddBlankSlide(mypres)
  mypres <- PPT.AddGraphicstoSlide(mypres,file=my_temp_file)
  unlink(my_temp_file) 

}

CalcCommission_Perc  <- function(Variable,FName,AxisAngle){
  Actual_Commission_Perc <- tapply((Converted_A$Commission/Converted_A$NetPremium)*100,Converted_A[Variable],mean)

Predicted_Commission_Perc <- (((tapply(Final_cut$Commission_Response*Final_cut$Origination.Demand,Final_cut[Variable],sum)/tapply(Final_cut$Origination.Demand,Final_cut[Variable],sum))/100)/
                                  (tapply(Final_cut$Prem_Net*Final_cut$Origination.Demand,Final_cut[Variable],sum)/tapply(Final_cut$Origination.Demand,Final_cut[Variable],sum)))*100

Data <- data.frame(x=names(Actual_Commission_Perc),Actual_Commission_Perc,Predicted_Commission_Perc)

  Commission_Perc_Plot <- ggplot(Data,aes(x=seq(length(unique(x))))) +
    geom_line(aes(y=Actual_Commission_Perc, colour = "Actual Commission %")) + 
    geom_line(aes(y=Predicted_Commission_Perc, colour = "Predicted Commission %")) +
    scale_x_continuous(name = FName, 
                       breaks = seq(length(unique(Data$x))), 
                       labels = unique(Data$x))   +
    scale_y_continuous(name = "Commission £") +
    ggtitle("Commission %") +
    theme(legend.title=element_blank(),axis.text.x = element_text(angle = AxisAngle, hjust = 1))

  mypres <- PPT.Init(method="RDCOMClient")
  mypres<-PPT.AddTitleSlide(mypres,title="Commission %",subtitle=date)

  ggsave(my_temp_file<-paste(tempfile(),".wmf",sep=""), plot=Commission_Perc_Plot)
  mypres <- PPT.AddBlankSlide(mypres)
  mypres <- PPT.AddGraphicstoSlide(mypres,file=my_temp_file)
  unlink(my_temp_file) 
  }

CreateGraph  <- function(Variable,FName,AxisAngle){

  CalcCommission(Variable,FName,AxisAngle)
  CalcCommission_Perc(Variable,FName,AxisAngle)
  }
CreateGraph("Age_Banded","Age",0)
CreateGraph("InstalmentsRequestedInd","DD Payment",0)
CreateGraph("NetPrem_Banded","Net Premium",45)
```

Comment: since this is a windows-only package (and almost four years old on cran) I can't install, but others can download from `devtools::install_github('cran/R2PPT')`. it would also help them if you made this into a small, reproducible example. I would also guess that `RDCOMClient ` is windows-only

Comment: Might want to explore the [`rvg`](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/rvg/index.html) package

Comment: You might try exporting to jpg and then insert the jpg in your powerpoint as a linked file...this lets you easily update your graphics from R and keep whatever formatting and text you have in the powerpoint document. This would be problematic if you were exporting a large number of graphics to powerpoint but since this usually isn't the case it's feasible.

Comment: I just made a package, export, that allows one to do just that... It's built on top of the officer package...

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to save two plots in one pptx file:

```
library(ReporteRs)
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)
pptx() %>%
  addSlide("Title and Content") %>% 
  addTitle("plot #1") %>% 
  addPlot(function() barplot( 1:8, col = 1:8 )) %>% 
  addSlide("Title and Content") %>% 
  addTitle("plot #2") %>% 
  addPlot(fun = print, x = qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, data = iris, color = Species, size = Petal.Width, alpha = I(0.7) )) %>%
  writeDoc(ppfn <<- tempfile(fileext = ".pptx"))
```

`ppfn` contains the PowerPoint file name including its path. Check out the package documentation [here](http://davidgohel.github.io/ReporteRs/powerpoint.html).

Comment: Note that [package ‘ReporteRs’ was removed from the CRAN repository](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ReporteRs/index.html), but archives are available.

Answer (score 0):

Answer above is outdated, as `ReporteRs` has been removed from CRAN and is superseded by `officer`. I just made a new package export built on top of `officer` that easily allows one to export several graphs to a single Powerpoint presentation using the `graph2ppt()` command and the `append=TRUE` option, e.g. to produce a presentation with 2 slides :

```
install.packages("export")
library(export)
library(ggplot2)
qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, data = iris, color = Species, 
      size = Petal.Width, alpha = I(0.7))     
graph2ppt(file="plots.pptx", width=6, height=5) 
qplot(Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, data = iris, color = Species, 
      size = Petal.Width, alpha = I(0.7))     
graph2ppt(file="plots.pptx", width=6, height=5, append=TRUE)
```